# Draw lines into skeleton joints (coordinates) with Python and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below represents the plotting of a graph that corresponds to the reading of a text file with n lines. Each line contains 4 columns,the first three columns are coordinates of (x,y,z) points, and the fourth column is a binary variable not necessary for this plotting.

At each 20 lines read, a skeleton is read, this skeleton being a group of 20 (x,y,z) points or joints, each joint made by the first three columns of each line.

The text file contains 860 lines, and 860/20 = 43, being 20 the number of joints to create a skeleton of (x,y,z) joints. Then, the text file is made of 43 skeletons, that generates a **movement**. Therefore, the text file *represents a movement*.

I'm having problems to build the edges (lines) that connect each (x,y,z) point to the others in a logic way so that the plotting of the points may look like a skeleton.That must be inside a loop, so that at each 20 lines read, a skeleton is generated and, after an event of key pressing, let's say the right arrow key, the next 20 lines are read and another skeleton is generated.

I'm a beginner both in Python and Matplotlib. I've posted the picture below for the skeleton generated by Matploblit without the edges, and another picture similar to the result I need to achieve with the edges.

An example of the text file content:

```
1.3200000e+002  8.0000000e+001  6.8100000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.6900000e+002  8.1000000e+001  6.6500000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.4800000e+002  7.5000000e+001  6.5000000e+002  0.0000000e+000
1.5100000e+002  9.8000000e+001  6.9800000e+002  0.0000000e+000
1.3200000e+002  1.2000000e+002  6.7400000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.6100000e+002  1.2200000e+002  6.6200000e+002  8.1730800e-001
```

Also, in the plotting of the skeletons, only two coordinates are taken, (x,y) to generate a 2D skeleton, so the third coordinate is ignored. And, the plotting is already inside a loop, but the key pressing event part is not implemented yet, the next skeleton is plotted when the current canvas is closed.

Also, you may notice that the plotting is generating an overlap of the previous skeleton to the next skeleton.I've posted a picture of the overlap too, which is one of the 42 skeletons generated after the first one.

First skeleton plotted without joints:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNFTL.png

One of the next 42 skeletons plotted without joints,with the OVERLAP problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8FQt.png

An approach of the needed result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkWUc.png

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import sys
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

movement = np.loadtxt("file01.txt")
number_of_postures = int(len(movement)/20)

listing = []
for i in range(number_of_postures):
    listing.append(movement[(i*20):((i+1)*20),:3]) 

matrixCoord = np.array(listing)

num_plots = number_of_postures
z = 0

for m in range(num_plots):      
   gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1]) # create figure at start of loop

    z += 20
    skeleton = movement[:z,:2]
    x = skeleton[:,0]
    y = -skeleton[:,1]
    plt.subplot(gs[1]) 
    plt.scatter(x,y, s=40)
    plt.title('Skeleton')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post the textfile so that we can see the data from which the lines should be plotted.

Comment: 1.3200000e+002  8.0000000e+001  6.8100000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.6900000e+002  8.1000000e+001  6.6500000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.4800000e+002  7.5000000e+001  6.5000000e+002  0.0000000e+000
1.5100000e+002  9.8000000e+001  6.9800000e+002  0.0000000e+000
1.3200000e+002  1.2000000e+002  6.7400000e+002  1.0000000e+000
1.6100000e+002  1.2200000e+002  6.6200000e+002  8.1730800e-001
7.9567300e-001     ***The file is too long, that's an example, it's 800 lines long***.

Comment: ok, I meant the 20 lines you wrote that form one skeleton - and even that wouldn't be necessary, perhaps 3 lines, so that an example of three lineplots could be set up

Comment: Note that you could post these few lines also like code in your question. This way we could see how the numbers are structured within the file. The comment above is unfortunately only a huge list of numbers which don't tell anything to someone not involved. Please add  a description how one line in your file describes a joint line to plot: which number means what (x1, x2, y1, y2 or whatever...)

Comment: I've altered the description.

Comment: So the information which pairs of xy-coordinates build lines and which not is not included in the file?

Comment: No, it's not included.

Comment: Ok, then at first you would have to create the list of bones,  that is: a 20-element list of the corresponding line numbers of the joints which build a bone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***First only the direct answers to your questions:***

**Plotting the lines between the joints:**
First create "list of bones", a list which contains all the pairs of joints which build a line of the skeleton. It can be obtained from the picture with the enumerated joints that you posted:

```
bone_list = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [1, 8], [2, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13], [5, 14], [6, 15], [14, 16], [15, 17], [16, 18], [17, 19], [3, 20]]
```

As the enumeration starts from `1` but python indices start from `0`, convert the list to a numpy-array to easily decrement all the values by 1:

```
bone_list = np.array(bone_list) - 1
```

With this prepared, you can draw the lines in your movement loop with an extra loop for each line (right after `plt.scatter(x, y, s=40)`):

```
for bone in bone_list:
    plt.plot([x[bone[0]], x[bone[1]]], [y[bone[0]], y[bone[1]]], 'r')
```

**and regarding your overlap-problem:**
this is just because in

```
skeleton = movement[:z, :2]
```

you slice always from zero on, i.e. [0:20, :2] in the first loop (drawing one skeleton), [0:40, :2] in the second loop (drawing two skeletons) and so on.
Change it to

```
skeleton = movement[z-20:z, :2]    # or [z:z+20, :2] and do z+=20 afterwards
```

***However, if I may add some general hints to your script:***

there are far too many imports (at least for the part you posted)
there are variables renamed which are already there
there are unused variables
you don't use the iteration variable `m` in your loop
`gridspec` is for creating subplots in an unequally distributed grid - do you need that?

With this in mind, the script you want could be like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

movement = np.loadtxt("file01.txt")
bone_list = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [1, 8], [2, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13], [5, 14], [6, 15], [14, 16], [15, 17], [16, 18], [17, 19], [3, 20]]
bone_list = np.array(bone_list) - 1
number_of_postures = int(len(movement)/20)

for i in range(number_of_postures):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(3, 8))
    plt.title('Skeleton')
    plt.xlim(100, 180)
    plt.ylim(-250, 0)
    skeleton = movement[i*20:(i+1)*20]

    x = skeleton[:, 0]
    y = -skeleton[:, 1]

    sc = ax.scatter(x, y, s=40)
    for bone in bone_list:
        ax.plot([x[bone[0]], x[bone[1]]], [y[bone[0]], y[bone[1]]], 'r')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've implemented all you've said above in two different files. The first one is an altered version of my original script that I've posted in the question, and I've added your answers to it. The second file is the script you've posted lastly, as a hint,but in that one, no canvas is being showed. I thought it could be something with the line: **fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(3, 8))**, and I removed "fig" from it, but then I got the error:  sc = ax.scatter(x, y, s=40): **TUPLE object has no attribute SCATTER**. I don't know why it's showing that error.

Comment: Please undo removing fig, I think the reason of no figure is shown is just a lacking plt.show(), which you have in your original script but I don't have in mine.

Comment: The reason for the error message after removing fig is, that now ax is getting the whole return value of plt.subplots, which is a tuple of a figure and the ax(es) within this figure. By assigning it to two variables fig and ax, this tuple is split and its elements go sparately into fig and ax.

Comment: I've added the plt.show() like that in the for loop: for i in range(number_of_postures):
    ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(3, 8))
    plt.title('Skeleton')
    plt.xlim(100, 180)
    plt.ylim(-250, 0)
    skeleton = movement[i*20:(i+1)*20]
    x = skeleton[:, 0]
    y = -skeleton[:, 1]
    sc = ax.scatter(x, y, s=40)
    for bone in bone_list:
        ax.plot([x[bone[0]], x[bone[1]]], [y[bone[0]], y[bone[1]]], 'r')
    **plt.show()**       ---But the "tuple" error remains.

Comment: Yes, i have to ask you to read carefully everything: please add fig again in front of ax = … and _additionally_ add plt.show()

Comment: Ok sorry for the lack of attention, now it's working perfectly!

Comment: Glad to know that. For better understanding of plt.show() and when it's necessary and when not, please refer to its manpage https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of reading, would you know some other reading that could help to understand how to connect each plotting of the loop into a key press event, I mean, the first plot is shown normally and the next plot of the loop comes when I press RIGHT ARROW KEY for example?

Comment: If you don't have to stick with the arrow key but would accept ENTER or RETURN, too, the easiest way to go would be to simply add "input('press ENTER to continue... ')" at the beginning of the loop

Comment: I've tried it but it's requiring to press ENTER inside the terminal, it must be an enter read that makes the canvas change with no connection to the terminal needed.

Comment: I'd like to implement something like what's explained here: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/event_handling/keypress_demo.html But I don't know how to adapt those examples to the code, since the code differs from the examples in certain aspects.

Comment: Right, "input ()" is a console command, so it needs focus there.